# With the Gigabyte 78LMT motherboard, can I use both discreet graphics and the integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I would like to add a third screen to my setup, but my graphics card only seems to support two (despite having three outputs, it seems as though you can't use HDMI and DVI at the same time).

My Motherboard is a Gigabyte 78LMT, and my graphics card is a Radeon R7 240. Is it possible with this configuration to add a third monitor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official chart of AMD ATI](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/r7/Pages/amd-radeon-hd-r7-series.aspx#4), it seems that your card only support 2 screens, your integrated graphics card is disabled when you plug in an external card, as far as I know, you can't enable it.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing that too. I would need a Graphics Card which supports Eyefinity, then I could use surroundview on my BIOS, just thought I would ask on here on the off chance that somebody has a work around.

Comment: After a little search, it seems impossible.. Anyway, if you don't really want to spend much money to plug-in your 3rd screen, there are USB to VGA adaptors, but I never tried one of them so be careful if you plan to buy one of them.